# zoom is not function in porto magento 2 demo 1 theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, magento-2.1.4

I'm frontend developer. I'm using `Smartwave porto magento 2 demo 1 theme`. Suddenly, on product detail page zoom on hover function not working. I have uploaded old `pub - static` folder where zoom was working properly. But still getting error in console `zoom is not function`. Even, I copied whole zoom function code where zoom function is called. Still no luck. Please let me know what I'm missing or where to check?. Thank you.

Comment: There may be the chance that an extension related to zoom is disabled, once check is that extension is enabled or deploy static content.

Comment: why this question is Upvoted ?

Comment: You should ask the vendor instead.